# Unable to use text center align in HTML CSS through SCSS/SASS

Tags: html, css, sass

If you see the code in codepen https://codepen.io/gladwin-james/pen/NWbrGWm I was able to center align the last line ***Almonds*** but I am using the exact code in my browser, I am not able to bring the ***Almonds*** to the center in my browser. that almond needs to be in center buts its not. I have also share the exact code below the image

[image: ![enter image description here]

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300&display=swap');
body {
  background: #e1e1e2;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-top: -15px;
}

.navbar1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  text-align: center;
  background: #292727;
  // box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #777;
}

.phone_favicon {
  width: 14px;
}

.navbar2 {
  margin-top: -15px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  text-align: center;
  background: #ffffff;
  // box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #777;
  padding: 5px;
  // border-radius: 8px
}

.the_line {
  color: black;
}

// Products //
.our_products_are_nuts {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: 'Poppins';
}

.nuts_expl {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  margin-top: -15px;
}

.nuts1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  margin-top: -15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="navbar1">
    <div class="container">
      <p> For Orders <img class="phone_favicon" src="images/phone.svg" alt="favicon-phoneicon"> +91 - 7299488343 / +91 - 7401429828</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar2">
    <div class="container">
      <p> <a href="#">Products</a>
        <span class="the_line"> | </span>
        <a href="#">Services</a>
        <span class="the_line"> | </span>
        <a href="#">About Nuts</a>
        <span class="the_line"> | </span>
        <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--//////////-->
  <div class="products">
    <p class="our_products_are_nuts">Our Products Are Nuts & Spice</p>
    <p class="nuts_expl">Call us to get Nuts and Spices at a best quality <br> and also at a best price</p>
  </div>
  <div class="pimary_products">
    <p class="nuts1">Almonds</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm confused not sure what to do. Kindly help. Help me align that Nut in center.

Yes I have also saved the program before executing,

Comment: most probably the browser cached of the previous alignment. so try by cleaning cache.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. It's centered on Firefox, Chrome and Edge. Make sure to refresh your browser and clear your cache. Maybe these files themselves are cached on your browser and you're not seeing the changes.

Comment: I would look for typos like missing brackets, missing quotes, unintended spaces etc. which one browser might tolerate and fix, but another one not. Also: do you have CSS rules for the class `.pimary_products` in your code? Or is that maybe a typo ("Primary/pimary")?

Comment: try to reproduce your issue or send the link where we can see it...I suggest not abusing the negative margins on the body. You can use to reset default margin, paddings on the body `html, body {margin: 0; padding: 0;}`. You can fix the top margin `navbar1 p {margin-top: 0;}` and CSS comments format is `/* comment */` instead of `// comment`

Comment: I know 2 cases when your issue will work. When `.nuts1` will be `display: inline-block/inline` or `pimary_products` the same `inline-block/inline`, or both)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how it worked but this is what I did. I am working in the IDE [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) I am using *.scss* file, so what happpend was the *.scss* file was not uploading itself in *.css*. I did a brief research and I couldnt find a proper solution.

I have installed the plugin **live sass complier** in VSC, so what I did was, I uninstalled the plugin **live sass complier** and resinstalled couple times. and this sorted the problem out for me.

And now the *.scss* file is uploading itself in *.css*.

I hope this helpful for someone.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the `// comment` with `/* comment */`.

```css
.navbar2 {
    margin-top: -15px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Poppins';
    text-align: center;
    background: #ffffff;
    /*box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #777;*/
    padding: 5px;
    /*border-radius: 8px*/
  }
  
  .the_line {
    color: black;
  }
  
  /*Products*/
  .our_products_are_nuts {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: 'Poppins';
  }
  
  .nuts_expl {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Poppins';
    margin-top: -15px;
  }
  
  .nuts1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Poppins';
    margin-top: -15px;
  }
```